# How to sort a file according to a column in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have a file which I want to sort according to a column in another file. Both files have a common column, and the sort should be according to the way the first file is sorted.

For example:
File_1 contains:

```
chr2L   2808299 2808300 EOG698VMB   4.15912 +   1011

chr2L   5218259 5218260 EOG6ZPFGT   15.0025 +   91

chr2L   5329859 5329860 EOG62JPCT   30.1536 +   30

chr2L   6225049 6225050 EOG60024V   3.26788 +   29

chr2L   6255843 6255844 EOG61C7HF   12.6259 +   32

chr2L   6481023 6481024 EOG6CZC26   1.33686 +   176

chr2L   8522135 8522136 EOG6FN543   40.2544 +   142

chr2L   9769068 9769069 EOG6FBJDN   17.8248 +   15

chr2L   9782391 9782392 EOG6R24FN   9.50656 +   393
```

File_2 contains:

```
chrXL_group1e   895799  895800  EOG67ST24   71.1687 +   62

chrXL_group1e   3113233 3113234 EOG6PVPKK   7.19303 +   847

chrXL_group1e   3424413 3424414 EOG6QC1SM   6.76991 +   81

chrXL_group1e   5698899 5698900 EOG651FCJ   93.5094 +   124

chrXL_group1e   6595546 6595547 EOG60K8KJ   28.349  +   185

chrXL_group1e   7594832 7594833 EOG6C2HX6   1.7771  +   2782

chrXL_group1e   8307304 8307305 EOG6NP7QS   229.754 +   35

chrXL_group1e   9922625 9922626 EOG6X3HMJ   8.8855  +   3744

chrXL_group1e   10297871 10297872 EOG6F7P63 2.70796 +   106

chrXL_group1e   11284647    11284648    EOG62Z5BX   282.474 +   4173

chr4_group5 213215  213216  EOG6J9NKZ   834.56  +   32

chrXR_group5    636614  636615  EOG6PVPK4   4.56969 +   152
```

I want to sort the contents of File_2 according to the order given in the column 4(protein ID) of File_1.
(There will be differences in the example. I can upload the original files if you want.) 
How do I do this in **Python**?
I do not think that the protein IDs are sorted in any particular way. But the way they are sorted in File_1 is important.

Other details:

Programming language: Python 3.5.1

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: In general I would say read in both files as pandas `DataFrame` and then merge them together, however your examples make it hard to see how the information to File 2 is related to that in File 1 (are you somehow matching on the first column?)

Comment: Use a dict mapping column element to index from the file that contains the sort order and use that dict as the key to sort

Comment: @NilsGudat No, I am matching the fourth column. The order of the fourth column should be same in both the files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function `sorted` can receive a keyword argument called `key`, which is a function that returns a comparable argument for each element of the list.

If you have two lists with the File_1 columns in in one and the File_2 columns in the other, you could use:

```
indexes = sorted(range(len(File_2Column)), key=lambda i: File_1Col4[i])
sortedFile_2Col = [File_2Column[i] for i in indexes]
# you can repeat this line for all the columns you want to be sorted by that order
```

Comment: So, how do I reorder the whole file? The other columns have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: after you assigned `indexes`, you can order any column using this line: `sortedFile_2Col = [File_2Column[i] for i in indexes]`